# regex groups to find a range

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `"age > 4 < 6"`

I would like to get the min and max range (4 being min and 6 being max)
without order being an issue, so `"age < 6 > 4"` should also work just as well as `"age > 4 < 6"`

I currently have:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<min>age.*?> ?[\d+] ?)(?P<max>age.*?< ?[\d+] ?)')
address = pattern.search('age > 4 < 6')
min, max = (address.group('min'), address.group('max'))
print min, max
```

But this does not work for me.

I am trying to use `.*?` to allow min to come before max or max to come before min - but to no avail!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> re.search('( < (?P<min>\d+)| > (?P<max>\d+))+', 'age < 4 > 6').groupdict()
{'max': '6', 'min': '4'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused with your question, but you can use two regexps:

```
text = "age > 4 < 6"
pmin,pmax = re.compile(r'age.*?< ?(\d+)'), re.compile(r'age.*?> ?(\d+)')
amin,amax = pmin.search(text), pmax.search(text)
min, max  = amin.group(1), amax.group(1)
print min, max
```